# SSRS Query execution failed for dataset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Have just deployed my Project on to my reporting Server.

I have multiple datasets which are referencing views which exist on the db on that server.

When I try to go into any report part I am getting this message:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
> Query execution failed for dataset 'dataset1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
> For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Can anyone help?

Comment: You'll need to check out your log files on the SSRS server for more detail.  They'll be somewhere like: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.DEV\Reporting Services\LogFiles\" or enable remote errors: "http://picnicerror.net/2012/04/11/enable-remote-errors-sql-server-reporting-services/"

Comment: You need to enable remote errors to pinpoint the problem. Otherwise you are guessing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I enabled remote errors to pinpoint the problem.

I identified that a column in a particular dataset (one of my views) was throwing an error.

So using a tool "SQL Delta", I compared the development version of the database with the live version on the reporting server. I noticed that one of the views had an extra column on the development server, that was not on the live version of the db.

SQL Delta generated the script I needed to run to update the view on my live db.

I ran this script, re-ran the report, everything worked.

Comment: Actual error is shown when report server is accessed with in the server it self (localhost).

Answer (score 9):

I encountered a similar error message. I was able to fix it without enabling remote errors.

In Report Builder 3.0, when I used the **Run** button to run the report, an error alert appeared, saying

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
[OK] [Details...]
```

Pressing the details button gave me a text box where I saw this text:

```
For more information about this error navigate to the report server
on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
----------------------------
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
```

I was confused and frustrated, because my report did not have a dataset named '`DataSet1`'. I even opened the `.rdl` file in a text editor to be sure.  After a while, I noticed that there was more text in the text box below what I could read. The full error message was:

```
For more information about this error navigate to the report server
on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
----------------------------
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)

----------------------------
The execution failed for the shared data set 'CustomerDetailsDataSet'.  
(rsDataSetExecutionError)
----------------------------
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
```

I *did* have a shared dataset named '`CustomerDetailsDataSet`'. I opened the query (which was a full SQL query entered in text mode) in SQL Server Management Studio, and ran it there. I got error messages which clearly pointed to a certain table, where a column I had been using had been renamed and changed.

From that point, it was straightforward to modify my query so that it worked with the new column, then paste that modification into the shared dataset '`CustomerDetailsDataSet`', and then nudge the report in Report Builder to recognise the change to the shared dataset.

After this fix, my reports no longer triggered this error.

Answer (score 7):

Like many others here, I had the same error. In my case it was because the execute permission was denied on a stored procedure it used. It was resolved when the user associated with the data source was given that permission.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the same issue, it was related to security not being granted to part of the tables. review your user has access to the databases/ tables/views/functions etc used by the report.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me came from [GShenanigan](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10847054/#comment14126464_10847054):

> You'll need to check out your log files on the SSRS server for more detail. They'll be somewhere like: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.DEV\Reporting Services\LogFiles\"

I was able to find a permissions problem on a database table referenced by the view that was not the same one as the where the view was.  I had been focused on permissions on the view's database so this helped pinpoint where the error was.

Answer (score 4):

I just dealt with this same issue. Make sure your query lists the full source name, using no shortcuts. Visual Studio can recognize the shortcuts, but your reporting services application may not be able to recognize which tables your data should be coming from. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, using Oracle you need to specify the DB Name, eg: `FROM DBName.Table`

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue showing the error

> For more information about this error navigate to the report server on
>   the local server machine, or enable remote errors Query execution
>   failed for dataset 'PrintInvoice'.

Solution:
1) The error may be with the dataset in some cases, you can always check if the dataset is populating the exact data you are expecting by going to the dataset properties and choosing 'Query Designer' and try 'Run', If you can successfully able to pull the fields you are expecting, then you can be sure that there isn't any problem with the dataset, which takes us to next solution.

2) Even though the error message says "Query Failed Execution for the dataset", another probable chances are with the datasource connection, make sure you have connected to the correct datasource that has the tables you need and you have permissions to access that datasource.

Answer (score 4):

In my situation, I created a new SSRS report and new stored procedure for the dataset. I forgot to add the stored procedure to the database role that had permission to execute it. Once I added the permissions to SQL database role with EXECUTE, all was fine!

The error message encountered by the user was *"An error occurred during client rendering. An error has occurred during report processing (rsProcessingAborted). Query execution failed for dataset "DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand) For more information..."*

Answer (score 3):

Very grateful I found this great post. As for my case, the user executing the stored procedure did not have `EXECUTE` permissions. The solution was to grant `EXECUTE` permissions for the user within the stored procedure by adding below code to the end of the stored procedure.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.StoredProcNameHere TO UsernameRunningreports
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had a very similar issue with a very similar error message.  My issue was that the database could not be connected to.  In our case, we have mirrored databases and the connection string did not specify the Failover Partner.  So when the database couldn't connect, it never went to the mirror and was throwing this error.  Once I specified the Failover Partner in the connection string for my datasource, it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

BIGHAP: A SIMPLE WORK AROUND FOR THIS ISSUE.

I ran into the same problem when working with SharePoint lists as the DataSource, and read the blogs above which were very helpful. I had made changes in both the DataSource and Data object names and query fields in Visual Studio and the query worked in visual Studio.  I was able to deploy the report to SharePoint but when I tried to open it I received the same error.

I guessed that the issue was that I needed to redeploy both the DataSource and the DataSet to SharePoint so that that changes in the rendering tools were all synced.

I redeployed the DataSource, DataSet and the Report to sharePoint and it worked. 
As one of the blogs stated, although visual studio allowed the changes I made in the dataset and datasource, if you have not set visual studio to automatically redeploy datasource and dataset when you deploy the report(which can be dangerous, because this can affect other reports which share these objects) this error can occur.

So, of course the fix is that in this case you have to redeploy datasource, dataset and Report to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue - I checked below things to fix this issue,

- *If you have recently changed pointing database-name in data-source

  then first check that all the store procedures for that report exist 
  on changed database.*
- *If there are multiple sub reports on main report then make sure each 
  report individually running perfectly.*
- *Also check security panel - user must have access to the databases/
  tables/views/functions for that report.*

Sometimes, we also need to check `dataset1` - store procedure. As if you are trying to show the report with `user1` and if this user doesn't have the `access(rights)` of provided `(dataset1 database)` database then it will throw the same error as above so must check the user have access of `dbreader` in SQL Server.

Also, if that store procedure contains some other database **(Database2)** like

```
Select * from XYZ inner join Database2..Table1 on ... where...
```

Then user must have the access of this database too.

**Note:** you can check log files on this path for more details,

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services
```

Answer (score 2):

**I got same error but this worked and solved my problem**

*If report is connected to Analysis server then give required permission to the user (who is accessing reporting server to view the the reports) in your model of analysis server.
To do this **add user in roles of model or cube**  and deploy the model to your analysis server.*

Answer (score 2):

Using SSRS, Report Builder 3.0, MSSQL 2008  and query to an Oracle 11G database,
I found that the oracle stored procedure ran well, produced consistent results with no errors.  When I tried bringing the data into SSRS, I got the error as listed in OP's query.  I found that the data loaded and displayed only if I removed the parameters (not a good idea). 
  On  Further examination, I found that under dataset properties>parameters I had set the start date to parameterName   P_Start and parameter Value to  @P_Start.

Adding the Parameter value as [@P_Start]  cleared the problem, and the data loads well, with parameters in place.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was caused by an orphaned SQL Login. I ran my favorite sp_fixusers script and the error was resolved.  The suggestion above to look at the logs was a good one...and it led me to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This might be the permission issue for your view or store procedure

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, it could be due to a missing **SQL stored-procedure** or **SQL function**.  For example, this could be due to the function not migrating from a non-prod region to the production (prod) region.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all comments from the Select Query fixed this for me. My dataset was working in the Preview but when I went to Design/Query Designer and and tried the query there I was getting ORA-01006;bind variable does not exist.  After removing all comments from the select it worked.

Comment: Depending on the code in question removing all comments can have drastically different results. I don't suggest blindly removing all comments and executing code.