# Cannot read next data row error in subreport

Tags: sql, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008, subreport

I have a report which runs fine by itself but when included as a subreport throws me this error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Cannot read the next data row for the dataset PersonalDetails.
>   (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow) For more information about this error
>   navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable
>   remote errors

Dataset:

```
SELECT  CAST(College_Year AS VARCHAR(10)) as CollYear
,[Photo_File_Name],[Learner_ID]
,[Gender],[Surname],[Forename_1],[Forename_2]
,[Learner_Date_Of_Birth],[Age],[AgeAt31Aug]
,[AgeGroup],[Title],[Ethnicity_Code]
,[Ethnicity],[Disability_Code],[Disability]
,[Learning_Difficulty_code],[Learning_Difficulty],[learner_Status]
,[Student_Addr_1],[Address_Locale],[Address_Town]
,[Address_County],[Post_Code],[Student_Home_Address]
,[Mobile_Number],[Home_Telephone],[Tutor]
,[Tutor_Name],[Tutor_Department],[EMA]
,[ALG],[Drop_Out_Status],[ALS_Cost]
,[School_Code],[School_Name],[Staff]
,[New_Learner],[Prior_Attain_Level],[Decesed]
,[Drop_Out_Date],[Record_Created],[Status_Drop_Out_Code]
,[Post_Code_DU_Uplift],[UCI_Number_S19],[DU_Code]
,[DU_Factor],[Main_Qualification],[Main_Qualification_Code]
,[Enhanced_Funding_L28a],[Nationality_Code],[Nationality]
,[About_Courses],[For_surveys],[Contact_Override]
,[By_post],[By_Telephone],[By_email]
,[NI_Number],[ULN],[L14]
,[Registered_disabled],[ALS_Asses],[Pastor_Tutor]
,[Pastor_Tutor_Title],[Pastor_Tutor_Name],[Date_Entered_the_UK]
,[L29],[Is_Staff],[Enrol_Status]
,[Texting_OptOut],[Learner_email_address],[Learning_Assessment_139A]
,[LDDPH_Health_Prob],[English_1St_Lang]
  FROM [NG].[dbo].[IM_ST_Students_vw]
where 
learner_ID = @learner_ID order by CAST(College_Year AS VARCHAR(10)) desc
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ar

Comment: To fix this error, you need to check few things like, check your dataset, also it can be related to security issue, not being granted to part of the table. please review your user has access to the table/database. Also if possible create same dataset again by removing existing one. Let me know, still if you facing issues. - Also you should check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847054/ssrs-query-execution-failed-for-dataset)

Comment: @pedram - yes I replaced dataset..not sure why this problem happens in sub-report which many reports use....

Comment: Aruna, similar to the previous problem, you need to narrow the problem space. In this moment, we do not know whether your problem originates from the select, the from or the where. Try the query without columns (select 1 from ...). If it can be executed, then your problem originates from a column. Then you will need to use the idea of binary search with your experiments to quickly find the exact column you have problems with.

Answer (score 2):

There is an in-depth description of the error

> **Problem**
>
> When accessing an IT Analytics report, the error "An error has
>   occurred during report processing. Cannot read the next data row for
>   the dataset 'dataset name'." occurs. Also, processing of cubes that
>   relate to the report may also result in issues.
>
> **Error**
>
> In IT Analytics reports:
>
> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>               Cannot read the next data row for the dataset 'dataset name'. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
>                            For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable
>   remote errors.
>
> In SQL when trying to process a cube or dimension:
>
> The server sent an unrecognizable response. "`<invalid-character>`,
>   hexidecimal value 0x`<hex-value>`, is an invalid character. Line
>   `<line-#.>`, position `<position-#>`. (System.Xml)
>
> **Cause**
>
> If invalid XML characters (i.e., certain non-alphanumeric characters)
>   are present in data, the Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Server (SSAS)
>   may not be able to process cubes and their dimensions. This is because
>   XML reserves certain characters that are non-alphanumeric in nature
>   for use as programming code. When these are seen in data, XML attempts
>   to process them as escape codes for code, but as they are not actually
>   code, it results in errors. This is therefore not a limitation or
>   issue caused by the IT Analytics product or by SSAS, but by the
>   contents of the user's data, however it was populated. This may occur
>   also if data becomes corrupted (SQL server crash, bad import, etc.)
>
> Additional information on this can be found on Microsoft's web sites:
>
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.dataitem.invalidxmlcharacters.aspx
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.invalidxmlcharacters.aspx
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.dataitem.invalidxmlcharacters(v=sql.90).aspx
>
> **Solution**
>
> **(1)** This article is only intended to troubleshoot and resolve the exact errors as shown above. If the user sees a different variation of
>   these errors, this article is most likely not applicable.
>
> **(2)** For simplicity of reading, the affected characters that are the issue, which are invalid XML characters, are from here on referred
>   to as "non-alphanumeric characters", as this is how they will appear
>   to the user. This does not indicate and should not be confused with,
>   however, that any non-alphanumeric character is an issue, but only
>   refers to those that will affect XML, as described in the URL
>   references in the Cause section, above.
>
> **(3)** "Non-alphanumeric charactes" refers to any non-standard or invalid character found that normally shouldn't be used. For example,
>   copyright symbols, trademark symbols, line graphics, or what appear to
>   be oriental letters (corrupted data, in this case). All letters,
>   numbers and standard characters such as hyphens, periods, + signs,
>   etc., are acceptable.
>
> **(4)** Symantec Technical Support is unable to assist the user in in-depth troubleshooting this issue based on the cause: their data is
>   invalid and SSAS directly cannot process the data. ITA is thereby
>   effected, but is not the cause of the issue in itself. The user must
>   themselves find and resolve any bad data that contains
>   non-alphanumeric characters. Please contact your DBA if you need
>   assistance in doing this.
>
> **Preferred Solution: Correct the data directly.**
>
> Check to verify which reports see this issue note their report names.
>   This generally only occurs for a single report, or a small number; all
>   others work successfully.
>
> Using the affected product's own reports (not ITA reports) or a SQL
>   script, locate and view those that are similar to the ones desired to
>   be used in IT Analytics. Do any columns and fields visibly contain
>   non-alphanumeric characters? For example, if "cost centers" was
>   appearing as the data set that has the issue in the error, review the
>   report found by clicking on the Reports button > All Reports > Service
>   and Asset Management > Organizational Types > Cost Center > List of
>   Cost Centers by Location. Do any of their names include invalid
>   characters?
>
> ```
> Cost Center Name
> Springfield©
> Lindon
> ```
>
> In the first cost center's name there is a non-alphanumeric character,
>   a copyright symbol "©". It doesn't make sense that there would be a
>   copyright symbol in a cost center's name and so this sticks out
>   visually as being invalid. This character may or may not be a reserved
>   XML character. If so, SSAS will not be able to process any cubes and
>   dimensions that reference this worker's name. Based on this, we know
>   that at the least, the cost center's Name field has non-alphanumeric
>   characters.
>
> This can be inspected in SQL too, for example:
>
> ```
> USE Symantec_CMDB
> SELECT *
> FROM vCostCenter
>   If the product reports do indeed show such non-alphanumeric characters, change these at their source. For example, for ServiceDesk
> ```
>
> users, if these were imported from Active Directory and the issue
>   exists there, change the user name there, then perform an update
>   import into ServiceDesk to change the user names there. Once changed,
>   then try re-processing the IT Analytics cubes in question to then
>   enable the IT Analytics ServiceDesk reports that previously did not
>   work to then work. Note: Depending on the scope of the amount of
>   non-alphanumeric characters, this may be a long and tedious process to
>   manually fix for the user.
>
> **Workaround: Change SSAS to ignore the non-alphanumeric characters.**
>
> Run Microsoft Visual Studio, preferably on the SQL Server, or at least
>   on a workstation that has access to the SSAS. Click on the File menu >
>   Open > Analysis Services Database. Type the SSAS's server name in the
>   Server field. Click on the dropdown field for Database and select the
>   SSAS database to edit. Click on the OK button. In the Solution
>   Explorer window, scroll down until Dimensions are displayed. Double
>   click on the dimension to edit. For example: "Computer". Note: The
>   dimension to edit will generally be very close or the same name as
>   appears in the error, the data set name referred to there. The user
>   may need to experiment with which one is the correct one to edit,
>   however. In the Attributes window, click on the dimension's attribute
>   to edit. For example, "Computer - Name". In the Properties window,
>   scroll down until the Source section is displayed. Click on the "+" to
>   expand the NameColumn field. Change the "InvalidXmlCharacters" field
>   from Preserve to either Replace (which replaces the non-alphanumeric
>   characters with a "?") or Remove (which completely removes the
>   non-alphanumeric characters). It is recommended to set this on all
>   unicode and non-unicode text attributes as potentially any off these
>   could include invalid XML characters. Repeat steps 7 through 11 until
>   all dimensions and affected attributes are changed. Click on the File
>   menu > Save All. This will prompt to save the changes.
>
> **Troubleshooting: Use SQL to help find the columns and fields that contain non-alphanumeric characters.**
>
> While it is beyond the scope of Symantec Technical Support to assist
>   in resolving data issues such as non-alphanumeric characters found in
>   the customer's data, the attached SQL script "Parse Tables and Columns
>   for Non-Alphanumeric Characters.sql" can help the user in finding
>   non-alphanumeric data. This script can be ran against any database
>   that is suspected of having non-alphanumeric characters
>   (Symantec_CMDB, ProcessManager, SEPM, etc.) that IT Analytics accesses
>   for data for its reports.
>
> **NOTES:**
>
> **(1)** This SQL script does not remove the data but only finds it for the
>   user.
>
> **(2)** Once the user determines which columns and fields contain
>   non-alphanumeric data, it is up to the user to determine how best to
>   resolve this. It is recommended to use the above solution and
>   workarounds to help with this.
>
> **(3)** Instructions on how to use the
>   script are found inside of it. Please note that this script will take
>   an extremely long time to run and it is not recommended to run against
>   a production database, at least during production hours, as
>   performance may drop. This is because this script will parse through
>   every table, column and field value looking for non-alphanumeric
>   characters. It does not change anything but only reports on what is
>   found. For example, on a small test database, this took seven hours to
>   run. It is therefore strongly recommended that the user is absolutely
>   certain that this is the issue and that the above listed solution and
>   workarounds do not work before even considering using this script.

[Source](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH186577.html). They also have a script which does not modify your data, but finds potential problems and shows them to you.

A person in 2006 [claimed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e86e614f-de46-48f3-b9a8-fbd1c8102b35/cannot-read-the-next-data-row-for-the-data-set?forum=sqlreportingservices) that he/she found an error, namely, data was occasionally converted to string. I am not sure whether the person was right and if so, whether the issue was resolved since then.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a Stored Procedure without the "public" permissions.