# Reporting service in TFS 2013

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, tfs-reports

Following Error shows when run report after configuring Reporting Service in TFS 2013

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'dsProjectGuid'.
>   (rsErrorExecutingCommand) For more information about this error
>   navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable
>   remote errors

Comment: possibly duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847054/ssrs-query-execution-failed-for-dataset

Comment: I have checked but can't comment where i have query???

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether the status of all configurations in TFS Administration Console--Reporting are configured well.

Then try to follow the steps below to manually process data warehouse and analysis services cube for Team Foundation Server:

1. Log on to the application-tier server and open the Warehouse Control Web Service by entering the following URL in a supported web browser:

http://localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx

2. Choose **ProcessWarehouse**, click **Invoke**:

[image]

3. Choose **ProcessAnalysisDatabase**. For **processingType**, type either **Incremental** or **Full**. Click Invoke:

[image]

To determine the processing status of the warehouse and Cube processing choose **GetProcessingStatus** to check the process status.

Detailed information check https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff400237%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I have followed all the steps but showing this error.

Comment: After processing the steps above, did you see any error when view GetProcessingStatus? Post the error here.

Comment: Showing this error    "[Full Analysis Database Sync]: ---> TF276000: The current Analysis Database Sync job has exited without making any changes. Either another Analysis Database Sync job is already in progress, or the Analysis Database Sync job cannot run because an Optimize Databases job is running. The next Analysis Database Sync job will start at its scheduled time."

Comment: Open Team Foundation Administration Console, select Reporting, check whether you have configured the jobs well, and test the connection. And try to rebuild the data warehouse and cube: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/rebuild-data-warehouse-and-cube

Answer (score 0):

At Last i have solved the above to configure it on Remote PC. following steps are followed:

1. Install SQL Server Feature such as Reporting Service, Analysis , Management Studio, Database Engine Service.
2. Configure Report using reporting services configuration tools.
3. In Reporting services Configuration, Create Database for Report.
4. Create Warehouse & Analysis database using TFS Admin console.
5. Start Job & Rebuild.
6. Manually Process Warehouse [Microsoft Guideline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube).
7. If Report folder is not appears then use TFPT Command.[guideline for using TFPT](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/upload-reports)
8. It takes time to full Process.
9. In Processing Time there appears some errors when run report such as "dsarea","dsiteration" Missing.
10. After Processing completely , it will works.